# Errors in Bluetooth SDK headers

Tags: c, sockets, bluetooth

```
#include <Bthsdpdef.h>
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2bth.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Bthprops.lib")


int main(void){
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err;
    DWORD qs_len;
    WSAQUERYSET *qs;
    DWORD flags;
    HANDLE lphLookup;
    int iRet;
    char buff[4096];
    LPWSAQUERYSET pwsaResult = (LPWSAQUERYSET) buff;
    DWORD buffLen = sizeof(buff);
    BTH_ADDR result;

    WORD wVersionRquested = MAKEWORD(2,2);
    err = WSAStartup(wVersionRquested, &wsaData);   //Statrup function

    if(err != 0){
        printf("WSAStartup failed");
        return 1;
    }

    qs_len = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
    qs = (WSAQUERYSET *) malloc(qs_len); // Save memory for  WSAQUERYSET structere
    ZeroMemory(qs, qs_len); //zero WSAQUERYSET out

    qs->dwSize = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
    qs->dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
    qs->lpcsaBuffer = NULL;
    flags = LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_FLUSHCACHE | LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_RETURN_ADDR; //details of the device discovery

    iRet = WSALookupServiceBegin(qs, flags, &lphLookup);
    if(iRet == ERROR_SUCCESS){
        printf("WSALookupServiceBegin failed");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\r\n\t\t\t\tScanning...");

    ZeroMemory(pwsaResult, sizeof(LPWSAQUERYSET));
    pwsaResult->dwSize = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
    pwsaResult->dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
    pwsaResult->lpBlob = NULL;

    while(WSALookupServiceNext(lphLookup, flags, &buffLen, pwsaResult) != ERROR_SUCCESS){
        result = ((BTH_ADDR)qs->lpcsaBuffer->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr);
        WSAAddressToString(qs->lpcsaBuffer->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH), NULL, (LPWSTR)buff, &buffLen);
        printf("Found: %s - %s", buff, qs->lpszServiceInstanceName);
    }

    WSALookupServiceEnd(lphLookup);
    free(qs);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

I got alot of syntax and missing type errors in bthsdpdef.h which is in microsoft sdk folder.
such as:

> bthsdpdef.h(11): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'LowPart',
>
> bthsdpdef.h(11): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines at the top of your file (above your #include's). That fixes the compilation for me.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 1 // Don't include Winsock v1
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

Your code needs to include the base header file(s). Otherwise when the compiler comes to bthsdpdef.h and sees the following it does not know the definition of type ULONGLONG.

```
struct SDP_LARGE_INTEGER_16 {
    ULONGLONG LowPart;
    LONGLONG HighPart;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a hint in the compiler error (I know, that's surprising but it really happens).

These are very probably C APIs, but you're compiling as C++. Your code certainly looks like C though, so double-check your compiler invocation.

Comment: I changed the compilation propreties in properties -> c/c++ ->advanced -> compile as C
and still there is errors :(